# Unifying interfaces LazySequence<T> and LazyFilteredSequence<T> in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

While implementing custom filtering values I has encountered the problem.
It is appeared when I tried to *combine* results from filtered and not-filtered LazySequences.

Here is sample to illustrate the problem:

```swift
let queryModulus: Int? = 10 // Sometimes may be **nil**
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].lazy // Actually comes from **external** source

let filteredValues = queryModulus.map { modulus in 
    values.filter { $0 % modulus == 0 } 
} ?? values // Error appears on this statement
```

When compiling above snippet compiler gives me error:

```
.code.tio.swift:4:59: error: cannot convert value of type 'LazyFilterSequence<[Int]>' to closure result type 'LazySequence<[Int]>'
let filteredValues = queryModulus.map { modulus in values.filter { $0 % modulus == 0 } } ?? values // Error appears on this statement
                                                   ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/srv/wrappers/swift4: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

The question is how to combine results of two expressions?

- filtered one `queryModulus.map { modulus in values.filter { $0 % modulus == 0 } }` that has type `LazyFilterSequence<[Int]>?`
- initial one `values` with type `LazySequence<[Int]>`

With quick research I realized that error appears on any collection.
It means that `LazySequence<T>` and `LazyFilteredSequence<T>` is incompatible for `Set`, and others.

You can [try.it](https://tio.run/##TY6xTsNAEET7fMUU0J0chwQKJMuioKCgikSDKBZnrZy0d2fu9ggO4tvNmRCEtpoZzdtJB9vrZpqEFW@Z4/gYdllyusWD1xYNVjWWS2yDY7WOExyNeGV4K4u5806Si9vgeWVwZbA22BhcG9y8VELHcS7fdZpJZEQXZkIfgwN/KEdPghRy7HjxA@utFJd3T2fo/0WVowGfcCcF639/V6dWiS5qXP7lTYMaX@Xa9jyyTLmPMUTQMDDFhOChe5uQlJQde52mbw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to add `.lazy` to the `.filter` inside your `.map` and then the return type of your `.map` and `values` will be identical.

```
let filteredValues = queryModulus.map { modulus in
    values.filter { $0 % modulus == 0 }.lazy
} ?? values
```

If you have a `Set.lazy` for your `values`, in your `map`, you first need to convert the result of `filter` to a new `Set` and then call `lazy` on that.

```
let setValues = Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).lazy
let filtered2 = queryModulus.map { mod in Set(setValues.filter { $0 % mod == 0}).lazy } ?? setValues
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for `[Int]`, but when `values` has `Set<T>` type, for example `Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` it unfortunately fails with same error.

Comment: @ValeryKameko so do you have an `Array` or a `Set`? Check my updated answer for how to get it working with `Set`.

Comment: It actually works! It seems that my question is bit unclear.